# JSDoc: combining (optional) @param and @type for getter/setter function-properties

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc, docblocks

How can one use `@param` to hint the *optional* param for a `function` that is a property (`this.selectedPage()`) *as well as* use `@type` to hint its return type?

Take this for example (`this.selectedPage()` can receive a page by passing a parameter and return one by passing none):

```
/**
 * @type {function(): Page}
 */
this.selectedPage = ko.observable(data.page);
```

The type-typehint is nicely picked-up by the IDE and allows for auto-completion of the fact that `this.selectedPage()` yields a `Page`.

However, please also note that `this.selectedPage()` takes a parameter - namely a page. Otherwise the IDE complains that the function allows 0 parameters when trying to pass one.

So I combined the two:

```
/**
 * @type {function(Page): Page}
 */
this.selectedPage = ko.observable(data.page);
```

This appears to stop the IDE from complaining when trying to pass a parameter, but now it complains when **not** passing one.

I tried `@type {function(undefined|Page): Page}` to no avail.

The function is a getter/setter - so how can one tell the docblock that @param is optional?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `@returns` for the return type?

Comment: Because it didn't work due to it being a property. I.e. @return works on function(){}, but not on this.func = func();. Unless it should and is an issue with the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, after reading-up on the JSDoc specs on various websites, I have now come across Google's Closure Compiler syntax that achieves what I've been trying to do - this is also properly picked-up by IntelliJ/PHPStorm.

Essentially, the optional parameter can be suffixed with `=`:

```
/**
 * @type {function(Page=): Page}
 */
this.selectedPage = ko.observable(data.page);
```

Or a more convoluted example:

```
/**
 * @type {function(Array.<Page>=): Array.<Page>}
 */
this.pages = ko.observableArray();
```

This does exactly what I want it to: documentation generators and IDEs recognise that the return value of `this.selectedPage()` and any items emitted by `this.pages()` are, in fact, of the type `Page` which, themselves, have all their properties recognised (since the `Page` type, too, is documented this way).

Similarly, I believe, this notation should also properly document the (optional) types that can be passed as parameters.